# how to redirect subdomain to actual website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

My host automatically sets up subdomains for all our hosted websites.  So that `zzz-thewebsite.myhosting.com` is the same files as `www.thewebsite.com` ...

Unfortunately, somehow google has indexed the subdomains and now I probably have duplicate content.

I'd like to remove the subdomains from the index.  I'm not sure the best way to do it.

I was thinking a .htaccess file that redirects `zzz-thewebsite.myhosting.com` to `www.thewebsite.com` would probably do the trick.  Of course, there are subfolders involved as well.

Is there an elegant solution for this?  I suppose a robots.txt might also do it but that will be in the both the `zzz-thewebsite.myhosting.com` and `www.thewebsite.com` "sites" since they are the same physical folder on the hosting.

Thank you.

Ben's answer below works great for me on non https sites but is not working for an https site.  What I am using is this:

```
#attempt to redirect subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewebsite-zzz.myhosting.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.thewebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]  

#https only  
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]   

#www only  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thewebsite.com [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.thewebsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: This depends a lot on *how* the subdomains are set up. I believe the only way to get Google to recognize them as the same site is to set up the sub-domains as a permanent redirect to the preferred domain.

Comment: However, it might also work to add [canonical links](https://yoast.com/rel-canonical/) in the HTML, which point to the full correct url on the correct domain, not just pointing to the homepage. That works for duplicate pages, if not for duplicate sites.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a permanent redirect is a preferred way.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zzz-thewebsite.myhosting.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.thewebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: It was too ugly formatted to put my need for further assistance in a comment so see my addition to my question above.  Thanks!

Comment: do you mean to redirect from `https://zzz-thewebsite.myhosting.com` to `https:///www.thewebsite.com`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.  Sorry it took so long to answer.  I would appreciate your help.  Somehow https://zzz-thewebsite.myhosting.com got indexed!

Comment: should refer moz (https://moz.com/blog/seo-guide-how-to-properly-move-domains) for the purpose of SEO, `301 permanent redirect` is a must for the domain name change.

Comment: Right.  I want to do a permanent redirect.  Your suggested method worked great for non-https sites (see notes above).  But it is not working on my https site.  More notes above in original post.

Comment: are the valid ssl certificates are installed in both sites?

Comment: Definitely.  Just tested to be sure, the https://zzz-thewebsite.myhosting.com site and the https://www.thewebsite.com both display properly with the green lock symbol.

Comment: you could try to test in incognito mode, see if the result the same?